# Add Python 2.7 to Anaconda 3 Without Internet

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I have a fire-walled linux environment which has no access to the internet. I've installed Anaconda 3 on it with python 3.5 but I need to add python 2.7 to it as well. I know I could normally use something like:

```
conda create python=2.7 -n py27
```

But in my case that will give me an HTTP error. Is there a way to get python2.7 in there without connecting to the internet? I can only scp files in there.

Comment: Maybe installing python from source...you need to get first the python 2.7 source on a pendrive or something https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/Python-2.7.tgz and then follow the instructions from http://www.diveintopython.net/installing_python/source.html

Comment: Hmm, only issue with that is that now I would have a separate directory for python 2, it wouldn't be merged within the bin folder of anaconda. For my purposes this is ok actually, but it would be nice if there were a way to easily integrate it into Anaconda. Keyword being 'easily' :)